# Synchronization between two MIT KDC does not work

Tags: kerberos, kdc

Setting up KDC -> Master and Slave
I did everything according to the [instructions](https://web.mit.edu)
All services have started succeeded
RUN
kprop -r {REALM} -f /var/lib/krb5kdc/dump {SLAVE fqdn}
is running successfully and after startup I see
Database propagation to {SLAVE fqdn}: SUCCEEDED

Creating a test user on master
I'm running kprop again -> SUCCEEDED
I go to the Slave server, I look through kadmin.local records, but I don't see the test user I created on the Master

How do I understand what the problem is or do I misunderstand this mechanism?

Comment: Is your kpropd service configured with the correct database path?

Comment: everything worked
my mistake was - instead of slave, I specified the master server when transferring the dump. By the evening I was tired and typoed there is a difference in the name server in one digit only
thank you